# semantic way to align the figcaption tag in html5

Tags: html

In html5, how can i align the `<figcaption>` tag to the top rather than at the bottom without using css.
Here are the snippets,

```
<figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock"
  width="304" height="228" />
  <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Is there any semantic way like `<figcaption align='top'>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put the `<figcaption>` as the first child of the `<figure>` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/EQaGU/)):

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228" />
</figure>
```

If you want the `<figcaption>` element as the last child, but shown above the image, then this is **presentational** and *should be done with CSS*.

---

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
> As the first or last child of a figure element.
>
> **Content attributes:**
> [Global attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#global-attributes)
>
> [Source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element)

Comment: @VijinPaulraj In HTML5 `align` is not a valid attribute anymore, because it is presentational.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj, only the attributes listed as [global attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#global-attributes) are allowed for `<figcaption>`.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj, no prob. Be sure to mark this answer as accepted, unless you need more information? Thanks!

Comment: @bfrohs, Accepted the answer!!